# How to Align this type of placeholder place in textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want exact this placeholder place

[image: expected placeholder place]

I try all alignments it's not work. This is my placeholder program to implement the white color:

```
[searchtextfield setValue:[UIColor whitecolor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: This above code will give color to your place holder, Please tell where exactly you want your placeholder aligned ?

Comment: yes ..i want to exactly placeholder place this page..

Comment: Please be clear with your question, can't make anything out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Objective c**

**For padding only placeholder this code will work**

```
usernameTF.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"    Your text"];
```

**For padding both placeholder and text of the UITextField this below code will work**

```
usernameTF.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(40, 0, 30);
```

**For Swift 3.0**

**For padding only placeholder this code will work**

```
self.usernameTF.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "    YourText")
```

**For padding both placeholder and text of the UITextField this below code will work**

```
usernameTF.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(40, 0, 30)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Swift 3.0 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to implement this and you also use this to multiple text fields :

First make a method of this :

create new file (nsobject) file name : Alert

**alert.m**

```
+(void) setLeftPaddingTextField:(UITextField *)textField paddingValue:(int) paddingValue
{
UIView *paddingView     = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, paddingValue, textField.frame.size.height)];
textField.leftView      = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode  = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}

+(void) setRightPaddingTextField:(UITextField *)textField paddingValue:(int) paddingValue
{
UIView *paddingView     = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, paddingValue, textField.frame.size.height)];
textField.rightView = paddingView;
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```

**alert.h**

//left padding

```
+(void) setLeftPaddingTextField:(UITextField *)textField paddingValue:(int) paddingValue;
```

//right padding

```
+(void) setRightPaddingTextField:(UITextField *)textField paddingValue:(int) paddingValue;
```

**your controller**

```
[Alert setLeftPaddingTextField:yourTextField paddingValue:20];
```

you can use this to many text fields with one defined method.